# Xamarin Forms ios only show one item in listview

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have searched on Google but the solutions proposed do not work for me.
I have a Listview like this:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" RowHeight="220" ItemTapped="OnResourceTapped" IsGroupingEnabled="false" CachingStrategy="RecycleElement">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Grid>
                        <ff:CachedImage VerticalOptions="Fill" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Aspect="AspectFill" Source="{Binding preview}"></ff:CachedImage>
                        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="End" Orientation="Horizontal" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource darkBlue}" Opacity="0.7" HeightRequest="40" Padding="10">
                            <StackLayout>
                                <Label Text="{Binding title}" TextType="Html" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" TextColor="{StaticResource white}" FontFamily="QuicksandBold"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding description}" TextType="Html" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" TextColor="{StaticResource yellow}" FontFamily="QuicksandRegular" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" MaxLines="1"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                            <ff:CachedImage Source="{Binding source, Converter={StaticResource SelfCareResourceTypeImage}}" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="30" Margin="0,0,10,0" Aspect="AspectFit"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

And in the ViewModel I have:

```
private ObservableCollection<SelfCareResource> items;
public ObservableCollection<SelfCareResource> Items
    {
        get { return items; }
        set
        {
            items = value;
        }
    }
...
public SelfCareViewModel()
    {
        string deviceLanguage = App.deviceLanguage;
        Items = new ObservableCollection<SelfCareResource>();
        _ = HTTPRequest.GetAllSelfCareResources(deviceLanguage, list =>
          {
              foreach (SelfCareResource item in list)
              {
                  Items.Add(item);
              }
          });
    }
```

The server returns me 12 resources and on Android it shows all but on iOS it only shows the first one

Comment: Try reducing the problem set to see if you can figure out the problem. Don't use a data template, and try manually populating the viewmodel Items. The more code you use to test, the more places there are for bugs to sneak in. Isolation is key.

Comment: Which thread are you adding items on?

Answer (score 0):

I make a simple example about the View Model. If you could make sure that the Items get all the item, it would show all. I tested on ios 15.2.

The View Model for your reference.

```
public class SelfCareViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<SelfCareResource> items;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ObservableCollection<SelfCareResource> Items
    {
        get { return items; }
        set
        {
            items = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Items"));
        }
    }
    public SelfCareViewModel()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<SelfCareResource>()
        {
            new SelfCareResource(){ title="A", description="aa", preview="YourImage", source="YourImage"},
            new SelfCareResource(){ title="B", description="bb", preview="YourImage", source="YourImage"},
            new SelfCareResource(){ title="C", description="cc", preview="YourImage", source="YourImage"},
        };
    }
}
public class SelfCareResource 
{
    public string preview { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string source { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that in iOS the property TextType="Html" in the labels does not work correctly. Thanks for the reply.